# Regression output tables from the rdrobust package in R

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and currently trying to make a regression table from my rdrobust results. This is an example of what i am aiming for:

[image]

I know that `rdrobust` is not supported by `modelsummary()` and that I have to use `tidy.rdrobust` and `glance.rdrobust` to make it applicable. So my question is how to specify the parameters in these two commands (tidy,glance) to get the desired output with the modelsummary package?
As shown in the picture I want to have the outcome variables/models as rows and the coefficients (with*),SE,z value and confidence intervals for the three rd methods as columns.

As I said I am relatively new to R and and completely new to programming language in general. Therefore this question is probably not specific enough and provided without any coding trials. Maybe someone can help me anyway.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Even though it does not satisfy all your requirements, you could leverage the function of `modelsummary`for side-by-side-models: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html

```
library(rdrobust)
library(modelsummary)

tidy.rdrobust <- function(model, ...) {
  ret <- data.frame(
    term = row.names(model$coef),
    std.error = model$se[, 1],
    p.value = model$pv[, 1]
  )
  row.names(ret) <- NULL
  ret
}

glance.rdrobust <- function(model, ...) {
  ret <- data.frame(
    Kernel = model$kernel,
    Bandwidth = model$bwselect
  )
  ret
}
```

If we implement with dummy data, it will show the following:

```
x1 <- runif(1000, -1, 1)
x2 <- runif(1000, -1, 1)
y1 <- 5 + 3 * x1 + 2 * (x1 >= 0) + rnorm(1000)
y2 <- 5 + 3 * x2 + 2 * (x2 >= 0) + rnorm(1000)

fit1 <- rdrobust(y1, x1)
fit2 <- rdrobust(y2, x2)
models <- list(fit1, fit2)
modelsummary(models, statistic = "p.value")
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Coefficient | X | X |
| Standart Error | X | X |

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is quite helpful, although I probably have to specify my other statistics like z values and confidence intervalls too in the tidy command? And if I dont need the kernel and bwselect information in my table, do I have to use the glance command at all?

Comment: It depends on the information of your table. It seems somehow cropped and you mentionned "glance.rdrobust" in your code.
But no, you may not need it at all if you don't need those information.